# gulp.pipe() and src() not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, browserify

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');


gulp.task('react', function(){

console.log("gulp is runnung");
});

gulp.src('src/App.js')
.pipe(browserify({
insertGlobals: false,
debug: true,
transform: [reactify]
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));

gulp.task("watch", function(){
    gulp.watch(["src/**/*.js"," src/**/*.jsx"], ["react"]);
    })

gulp.task("default", ["watch"]);

module.exports = gulp;
```

New to Gulp not sure what to do here
I installed every dependency
gulp,
reactify and browserify

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
 ^

TypeError: gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\geilkea\Desktop\my-project\src\gulpfile.js:16:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at [eval]:1:12
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:132:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:309:38)
```

This is the error im getting do I have to require something else?

Comment: Your `gulp.src` etc. part in the middle isn't in a task - it has to be.  Also look for a migration guide from gulp v3 to v4.  You are using gulp v3 syntax in a v4 file.